# How can I redirect to intent related to user input keyword in dialogflow

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dialogflow-es

I have created a technology bot agent in dialog flow where I prompt user to put any technology name and it will ask for confirmation . This will hit confirm name intent ( same with response "no" , that will hit no confirmation intent).

On confirming by typing yes , I did `Thanks. Lets begin with #awaiting_name_confirm.language`on response. for example:- if an user type **angular** , he will prompt confirm question. On typing yes , it will show `Thanks. Lets begin with angular`.

Now I want to create set of questions for each technology. For that I have created separate intent for angular , node etc.

How will user input (in case **angular**) upon confirmation will hit the intent angular ? If user input node , he must hit node intent and ask node questions etc. ? How can I achieve that ?

Answer (score 3):

Changing the response based on user input can be quite a challenge if you are only using the Dialogflow UI. The easiest way to respond with a set of questions based on user input would be by using [fulfillment](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/fulfillment-overview).

**Fulfillment**

With fulfillment you can use code to detect certain keywords or properties within your users input. In your case, if you are not already using it, it would be helpful to create a custom [entity](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/entities-custom) for each technology (Angular, node, etc). If you do this you do not have to look through the user input for specific words.

To be able to detect the entities through code, you need to setup your intent to work with your entity by using [parameters](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/tutorials/build-an-agent/create-intent-with-parameters). Once that is setup you can start detecting the technology that the user said and respond accordingly through code. A simple example of that would be:

```
app.intent("Technology Intent", (conv) => {
    const technology = conv.parameters.technology <-- Name is the same as the parameter in Dialogflow

    switch(technology) {

    case "Node": 
      conv.ask(askANodeQuestion())
    break;

    case "Angular":
      conv.ask(askAAngularQuestion())
    break;
});
```

Using this setup you would be able to setup different questions for each technology and trigger them by using the value of the parameter.

**Dialogflow Web UI**

While I do not recommend this approach, it would be possible to setup a conversation that triggers question based on the input of the user via the Dialogflow UI. You can setup an intent where you ask the user which technology they want to ask about and after that you create a [follow-up intent](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/contexts-follow-up-intents) for each technology and from there start building your questions.

[image]

This setup is useful for you if you dont want to use any code in your bot, but it does make the setup in Dialogflow rather complicated and harder to  maintain. So if you are going for a bot that you wish to use on the long term or expand upon in the future, I really recommend the fulfillment aproach with [context](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/contexts-overview).

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation. I got all your points though , I am new in DialogFlow and didn't put my hand on code yet , so I have less idea to start with code. Although for now I am using context to transfer user input to different intent. For your statement: `You can setup an intent where you ask the user which technology they want to ask about` , this is same as dynamically passing user input where I am facing problem. How will (angular) intent knows that user has typed angular?

Comment: Also suppose , if an user chose Node , if user ask any questions related to node then how will the intent knows those questions instead manually adding follow up intents? I have uploaded FAQ for various technologies in knowledge section but unable to trigger that ? How can I link particular faq with a particular intent?

Comment: To answer your angular question, no it is not the same as dynamicaly passing values. The angular intent is just a different intent and you should enter Angular as a training phrase. As for your other question, please create a new stackoverflow question for that, it is easier then doing everything in the comments

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. I will create another question after some research.

Comment: Added the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61673969/how-to-connect-a-document-in-knowledge-base-to-a-particular-intent-in-dialog-flo